# AJAX not called 2nd time on button click using jQuery click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an AJAX call on button click. The form is being submitted when I click the button first time. I'm showing an error message if there is an error.

But AJAX is not being called 2nd time when I click the button again. 
If I try an alert message instead of AJAX call, it is working fine. 
How do I make AJAX request 2nd time on button click?

Here is my code:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {


          $("#del").on('click',function()
           {
             $.ajax({
                type: 'DELETE',
                url: window.location.href,
                success: function(data) {
                  var error = data.error;
                  var success = data.success;
                  if(error.length>0)
                  {
                      $("#errmsg").attr('class', 'alert alert-danger alert-dismissible');
                      $('#str').text(error);
                      $('#errmsg').show();
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    $("#errmsg").attr('class', 'alert alert-success alert-dismissible');
                    $('#str').text(success);
                    $('#errmsg').show();
                      setTimeout(function(){
                        window.location.href= "/users";
                      }, 2000);
                  }
                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                    alert(textStatus+errorThrown);
                }
            });

          });



        });

        </script>
```

Comment: `type: 'DELETE',` ? `POST or GET`?

Comment: @guradio, `type: 'DELETE'` is valid

Comment: I see thank you for clarification @Satpal

Answer (score 0):

The key lies in the success handler of your script. You are changing the location of the page (i.e. redirecting) to your /users URL after 2 seconds if no error occurred.

I'm also assuming that this specific script, which attaches the event to the button, doesn't get included in the /users page, which would cause the event handler not to be triggered again when clicking the button.

So, I would recommend that you put that piece of code in a script file and reference it in both pages that you are loading.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few thoughts on this.

do you have the **#del** button always in the DOM? Or do you remove it and then append it to the DOM on every ajax call you make?

If yes, then the binding won't work, because you just created a new **#del** button.

So instead, try,

```
<div id="del" onclick="del_me()">Delete</div>

<script>
del_me = function(){
 //---- YOUR AJAX CALL HERE
}
</script>
```

or, if you don't want this, you would have to bind the click to the div each and every time you create the button.